# Relation Between Homologies of $X$ and it's Suspersion $\Sigma X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm reading how May's "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" and I have some questions about following proof: LEMMA (see pages 97-99). Here the excerpt:

[image]

We have the wedge product $X= \vee_i S^n$

1. How he reduces the case to one sphere? I suppose to get this one needs an isomorphism $\tilde{H}' _n (\vee_i S^n) \cong \oplus_i \tilde{H}' _n ( S^n)$ and resp $\tilde{H}' _{n+1} (\Sigma \vee_i S^n) \cong \oplus_i \tilde{H}' _{n+1} ( \Sigma S^n)$

How to obtain it or did the author had another argument in mind?

2. I guess that the case $\tilde{H}' _n ( S^n) \cong \tilde{H}' _{n+1} ( \Sigma S^n)$ is then just Freudenthal? I'm a bit curriuos why that isn't mentioned here.

Comment: By assumption on dimension the map $\vee S^n\hookrightarrow \prod S^n$ is sufficently connected to induce the first isomorphism in the chain $\pi_n(\vee S^n)\cong \pi_n(\prod S^n)\cong\bigoplus\pi_n(S^n)\cong \bigoplus\tilde H'_n(S^n)$, where we have assumed the wedge, and hence product, is finitely indexed.

Comment: @Tyrone: Hi. What do you mean with that " $\vee S^n\hookrightarrow \prod S^n$ is sufficently connected to induce the first isomorphism" (so $\pi_n(\vee S^n)\cong \pi_n(\prod S^n)\cong\bigoplus\pi_n(S^n)$)? Hornestly, I don't understand this argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $n\geq 2$ and give $S^n$ the CW structure with one $0$-cell and one $n$-cell. Then the $k$-fold product $\prod^k S^n$ naturally has the product cell structure with $k\choose r$ cells of dimension $r\cdot n$ for each $0\leq r\leq n$. In particular its $n$-skeleton has one $0$-cell and $k$ n-cells and is precisely the $k$-fold wedge $\bigvee^k S^n$.

The next cells of $\prod^k S^n$ occur in dimension $2n$, so in particular the inclusion of the $n$-skeleton

$$j:\bigvee^kS^n\hookrightarrow \prod^kS^n$$

is a $(2n-1)$-connected map. Since we are working under the assumption that $n\geq 2$, we have $2n-1\geq n+1$, and so the map on homotopy groups induced by $j$ is an isomorphism in degree $n$

$$j_*:\pi_n\left(\bigvee^kS^n\right)\xrightarrow{\cong}\pi_n\left(\prod^kS^n\right).$$

The definition of $n$-connectedness of a space, and more generally a map, appears in section *10.4 - The Cellular Approximation Theorem* of May's book. In deriving the isomorphism above we haven't used any machinery more advanced than basic CW theory, and if you are uncomfortable with anything here, then I would suggest a thorough reading of that entire chapter.

It now follows directly from the definitions that

$$\tilde H'_n\left(\bigvee^kS^n\right)\stackrel{def}{=}\pi_n\left(\bigvee^kS^n\right)\xrightarrow{\cong}\pi_n\left(\prod^kS^n\right)\cong \bigoplus^k\pi_n(S^n)\stackrel{def}{=}\bigoplus^k\tilde H'_n(S^n)$$

is a free abelian group of rank $k$. The second isomorphism follows from the general fact that $\pi_r(X\times Y)\cong\pi_k(X)\oplus\pi_k(Y)$. Since the product is finitely indexed it becomes a direct sum rather than product in the category of abelian groups. Moreover this isomorphism is given by sending a homotopy class $\alpha:S^n\rightarrow \prod^kS^n$ to the collection $(pr_a\circ\alpha)_{a\leq k}$, where $pr_a$ is the projection onto the $a^{th}$ factor. The point of this is that it tells us that $\pi_n\left(\prod^kS^n\right)$ is generated by the inclusions $i_a:S^n\hookrightarrow\bigvee^kS^n\hookrightarrow \prod_kS^n$, and so $\tilde H'_n\left(\bigvee^kS^n\right)=\pi_n\left(\bigvee^kS^n\right)$ must be generated by the inclusions $i_a:S^n\hookrightarrow\bigvee^kS^n$. Here $i_a:S^n\hookrightarrow \bigvee^kS^n$ is the inclusion of the $a^{th}$ wedge summand.

Now observe there is a canonical homeomorphism

$$\Sigma\left(\bigvee^kS^n\right)\cong \bigvee^k\Sigma S^n\cong \bigvee^kS^{n+1},$$

which is such that $\Sigma i_a$ identifies exactly with the inclusion $i'_a:S^{n+1}\hookrightarrow \bigvee^kS^{n+1}$ of the $a^{th}$ wedge summand.

Now still assuming $n\geq 2$ we return to the previous isomorphism and replace $n$ with $n+1$. This gives that $\tilde H'_{n+1}\left(\bigvee^kS^{n+1}\right)$ is free abelian of rank $k$ and is generated by the inclusions

$$i'_a=\Sigma i_a$$

which are in the image of the suspension homeomorphism. Since the domain of the suspension $\tilde H'_n\left(\bigvee^kS^n\right)$ is free abelian of rank $k$, and it takes generators to generators, the suspension is an isomorphism. Hence we answer your second question.

It remains now to wrap up the case of $n=1$. One first uses the generalised Van Kampen theorem to show that the fundamental group of $\bigvee^kS^1$ is the $k$-fold free product $\pi_1(\bigvee^kS^1)\cong\ast^k\mathbb{Z}$, and is again generated by the inclusions $i_a:S^1\hookrightarrow \bigvee^kS^1$. The abelianisation of this group is the free abelian group $\bigoplus^k\mathbb{Z}$ of rank $k$, and this group is generated by the images of the generators $i_a$ in the quotient $\pi_1(\bigvee^kS^1)_{ab}$.

The point of this is that the suspension

$$\Sigma: \pi_1\left(\bigvee^kS^1\right)\rightarrow\pi_2\left(\bigvee S^2\right)\cong\bigoplus^k\mathbb{Z}$$

in this case is not an isomorphism, but rather an abelianisation. Given the definition $\tilde H'_1(\bigvee^kS^1)=\pi_1(\bigvee^kS^1)_{ab}$ we see that even in this case

$$\Sigma: \tilde H'_1\left(\bigvee^kS^1\right)\xrightarrow{\cong}\tilde H'_2\left(\bigvee S^2\right)\cong\bigoplus^k\mathbb{Z}$$

is an isomorphism.